# Joining over different columns

Tags: json, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to get JOIN to work right on data in an Azure DocumentDB database.

I have a bunch of documents representing purchases, i.e. like

```
{
  "Timestamp": "2016-02-22T15:05:09.9863478+01:00",
  "MessageTemplate": "Processed {@Purchases}",
  "Level": 2,
  "Exception": null,
  "RenderedMessage": "Processed { Name: \"FunnyBibs\", Quantity: 112, PurchasedAt: \"Store2\" }",
  "Properties": {
    "Purchases": {
      "Name": "FunnyBibs",
      "Quantity": 112,
      "PurchasedAt": "Store2"
    }
  },
  "id": "2d919bbc-2763-47ea-9cc0-ee41cd6adb96"
}

{
  "Timestamp": "2016-02-22T15:05:09.8462592+01:00",
  "MessageTemplate": "Processed {@Purchases}",
  "Level": 2,
  "Exception": null,
  "RenderedMessage": "Processed { Name: \"Hats\", Quantity: 11, PurchasedAt: \"Store1\" }",
  "Properties": {
    "Purchases": {
      "Name": "Hats",
      "Quantity": 11,
      "PurchasedAt": "Store1"
    }
  },
  "id": "d6a5244b-92ef-4785-a065-dc45790f87b4"
}

{
  "Timestamp": "2016-02-22T15:05:09.6886969+01:00",
  "MessageTemplate": "Processed {@Purchases}",
  "Level": 2,
  "Exception": null,
  "RenderedMessage": "Processed { Name: \"Drinks\", Quantity: 4, Store: \"Store1\" }",
  "Properties": {
    "Purchases": {
      "Name": "Drinks",
      "Quantity": 4,
      "Store": "Store1"
    }
  },
  "id": "ed1ee4e4-862e-412e-9f37-05a5925c4c09"
}
```

Some of the documents have specified a "PurchasedAt"-property and others have a "Store"-property.

I would like to extract Name, Quantity and the shop the item was purchased at by joining document on "Store"-property and "PurchasedAt"-property such that I can get a feeling of how many items were purchased at the same place.

So I wrote this JOIN statement - but I cannot figure out how to get ANY data in return.

```
SELECT soldAt.PurchasedAt, item.Properties.Purchases.Quantity
FROM item
JOIN soldAt IN item.Properties.Purchases.PurchasedAt
WHERE item.Store = soldAt.PurchasedAt
```

So what am I doing wrong? I realize that the JOIN syntax looks pretty much like T-SQL, but the subtle differences still have me puzzled :-| .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocumentDB does not support inter-document joins, only intra-document (self) joins for the purpose of formatting the output. To accomplish your goal, you could fetch and aggregate using PurchasedAt, and then go back to get more Store details - -  two queries essentially accomplishing a join.

Comment: hey, so when they write "Let’s learn about the JOIN clause. DocumentDB’s JOIN supports intra-document and self-joins. Run the query below to iterate on the food document’s tags." at https://www.documentdb.com/sql/demo (the JOIN tab), that is not so?

Comment: I had a typo in my original answer. I meant to say that it only supports intra-document (self) joins. It's fixed now. Does that make more sense? The JOIN example on the demo page is an intra-document (self) join. If you meant to add an additional example, it didn't show up in these comments.

Comment: @JesperLundStocholm inter and intra document joins are two separate concepts. An Intra-document join is within the same document only and is what the DocumentDB example is demonstrating. The inter-document join is between different documents and is not supported at this time. It can be confusing because the words sound very similar but have different meanings.

Comment: @LarryMaccherone thank you - no I did not add an additional example in my comment :-)